# Background color on hover & padding

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with having a background color on hover, on a logo and also **padding around some images**.

For the background-color, it's for the logo that you see on the navigation bar on the left that is CAUL/CBUA. Its' hover state switches to [this image](http://redsky.incredifull.com/imgs/navi-hover/caul_blue_nav.png) and the background on hover should fill the whole block just like the links beside it.

For the padding of the images, it's on the **same** navigation bar, to the right. They are the social icons I'm sure it's not hard to see where the padding should be.

[Here's the link to what I have so far. You can see the navigation bar here.](http://redsky.incredifull.com/)

And here's my CSS:

```
/* Navigation bar */
#navi {
height: 40px;
background: #1e416f;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#navi a:hover {
background: white;
color: #1e416f;
}

.logo {
margin: 5px;
padding: 0;
float: left;
}

.logo a {
float: left;
margin: 2px 10px;
width: 36px;
height: 26px;
background: url(/imgs/navi/caul_white_nav.png) left top no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;
}

.logo a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/caul_blue_nav.png) left top no-repeat;
}

#primary-nav, #tools-nav {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#primary-nav li, #primary-nav a,
#tools-nav li, #tools-nav a { float: left; }

#primary-nav a, #tools-nav a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0 10px;
border-right: 1px solid white;
line-height: 40px;
}

#primary-nav li:first-child a, #tools-nav li:first-child a {
border-left: 1px solid white;
}

#tools-nav {
float: right;
}

#tools-nav .icon a {
text-indent: -9999px;
}

#tools-nav .email a {
background: url(/imgs/navi/mail.png) no-repeat;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .email a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/hover_mail.png) no-repeat;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .twitter a {
background: url(/imgs/navi/twitter.png) no-repeat;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .twitter a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/hover-twitter.png) no-repeat;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .search a {
background: url(/imgs/navi/search.png) no-repeat;
width: 20px;
}

#tools-nav .search a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/hover_search.png) no-repeat;
width: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<div id="navi">
<h1 class="logo"><a href="#">CAUL/CBUA</a></h1>

<ul id="primary-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Directories</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Committees</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="tools-nav">
    <li class="login"><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
    <li class="email icon"><a href="#">Email</a></li>
    <li class="twitter icon"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
    <li class="search icon"><a href="#">Search</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant HTML as well?

Comment: @RyanHenderson Added the relevant HTML! :)

Comment: size of the whole logo place is 56x30...so why you don't change tha attributtes of original picture? it's easier...another way is to add whole logo to div...i don't see another solutions

Comment: @webfix Because I was asked to use HTML, CSS and the images provided without changing their size.

Comment: then in my opinion you should create div which will wrap those images and change background for whole div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this method on active and hover. (background position center center).

```
#tools-nav .email a {
        background: url("/imgs/navi/mail.png") no-repeat scroll center center transparent;
        width: 20px;
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

May be this will help someone:

```
.menuItem:hover
```

and

```
.menuItem :hover
```

is not the same, take care!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#navi.logo {
margin: 5px;
padding: 0;
float: left;
}

#navi .logo a {
float: left;
margin: 2px 10px;
width: 36px;
height: 26px;
background: url(/imgs/navi/caul_white_nav.png) left top no-repeat;
text-indent: -9999px;
}

#navi .logo a:hover {
background: url(/imgs/navi-hover/caul_blue_nav.png) left top no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector are being overwritten do to CSS Selector scope/order. The more specific overwrites those that are more general, in this case, `#navi a:hover` is overwriting, `.logo a:hover` making your hover affect not work. the property you are overwriting is `background` change it to `background-color: white;` and you'll be fine